# Creating custom Cell in NSOutlineView which uses Core Data IB Bindings

Tags: cocoa-bindings, custom-cell, nsoutlineview, nsarraycontroller, nstreecontroller

I have an NSOutlineView that displays a hierarchy of folders taken from a Core Data entity using IB Bindings.  The NSOutlineView NSTableColumn is bound to an NSTreeController.  Each cell when clicked displays details in a CollectionView from an IB NSArrayController.ArrangedObjects with ArrayController.selectionIndexes.

What I now want is to create my own custom cells at the top of the NSOutlineView for things like "View all folder details" and "details added today".  I am not sure on the correct way how this is done when using IB Bindings.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: Do you want custom cells with a custom look or do you want extra rows with custom data?

Comment: Sounds like custom controls atop the table, implemented as fixed rows.   But there's not much reason to have controls in the top rows unless you definitely want those controls to scroll out of sight...

Comment: At the moment I would prefer fixed nodes at the top of the treeview.  Virtual nodes so to speak as they do not exist in core data.  Down the line I would like to display icon + text + leaf.count within the cell too so I guess that would mean moving over to a View based outlineview.  Sorry to clarify, I do not need these custom rows to be from core data or use bindings.  Programatically created and handled is fine too.

Comment: @stevesilva I though of adding another Outline View above the core data bound outline view and just place them together but was looking at options before I start.

Comment: Does the outline view display static data or can the data change?

Comment: It fetches data from a core data store that changes. It is all automatic using bindings so far.

Comment: It won't be automatic when the tree controller isn't in entity mode and a tree controller in entity mode can't handle custom objects.